# Is it appropriate to Create a server instance with a Singleton?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm creating a multiplayer game and I need to program a server. Now I'm thinking of designing it with the singleton pattern because I only want one instance of the server that all players connect to.  I'm relatively new to design patterns and I've seen a lot of negativity towards using the singleton pattern so I'm not sure if it's appropriate.

I'd appreciate any feedback and will try respond as soon as possible if you need more information on my problem.

Comment: A singleton is used to make sure a given class is only instantiated once in a given JVM (for a given ClassLoader, in fact). Your clients don't run in the same JVM as the server, so whether the server is implemented as a singleton or not doesn't change anything: that won't prevent anyone to start multiple instances of the server, on several JVMs or machines.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense I figured I'd ask rather than charging in and over designing it.

Comment: Not to go crazy on the Singleton but would it then make sense to have the client be a Singleton. because I only want one copy of the client running on each pc.

Comment: Once again, a singleton doesn't prevent multiple clients to run in parallel on a given machine. It only prevents the same class to be instantiated multiple times in a given Java program.

Comment: ah I think I'll stop trying to cram it in.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the singleton pattern violates single responsibility. This is true since the class will both manage its own creation and life-cycle.

I would prefer a dependency injector that can specify whether or not the class you are injecting is a singleton or not.

For example this is how ninject does it https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

```
kernel.Bind<MyClass>.To<MyClass>().InSingletonScope();
```